# change class of div in html page (located inside iframe) according to parent title

Tags: javascript, html

In my site i built a textual menu as menu.html inside iframe.each href i put in seperate div. i wanted that according to title of parent page the class of one of the divs  will be changed (for example:if title of parent is "home" then class of the aforementioned div changes to 'marked'). i have tried the following script but still it deosn't work. what is wrong? thanks again!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
switch (window.parent.document.title) {
case "hoempage":document.getElementById("nada1").className="marked"; break;
case "about": document.getElementById("nada2").className = "marked"; break;
        case "jokes": document.getElementById("nada3").className = "marked"; break;
        case "freewares": document.getElementById("nada4").className = "marked"; break;
        case "links": document.getElementById("nada5").className = "marked"; break;
        default: alert("god damn!"); break;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<ul class="menu1">
<li><a href="Index.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada1">homepage</div></a></li>
<li><a href="About.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada2">about</div></a>  </li>
<li><a href="Jokes.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada3">jokes</div></a></li>
<li><a href="freewares.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada4">freewares</div></a>    </li>
<li> <a href="NetGames.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada5">links</div></a>    </li>
</ul>
<br /><br /><hr />
<div class="write_mail">if you want to rgister to site updates enter name + email:
<form action="sent.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="subscr" /><br />email
    <input type="text" name="perosnal"/><br />name
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="alert('good job and thanks!');"/>    </form></div>

</body>
</html>
```

edited: i tried the solutions but nevertheless it still decline working. here is the parent code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<iframe src="menu.html" class="navibar" height="430px" width="50px" scrolling="no" style="border-style:none"></iframe>
<br />
<p class="About">built by zetta the beginner 2012<br /> 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the menu.html is the code i updated at the begining of the message.
sorry again for harassment :(

Comment: Are the pages from the same domain?

Comment: windows is not an object. type error? and case no break?

Comment: same domain, there are breaks and it still refuse working. suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page that embed the iframe code as follow:

```
      <html>
<head>
<title>main</title>
<style>
.marked{background:yellow}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="class1">dddddddddddddddd</div><div id="class2">dddddddddddddddd</div>
<iframe src="iframe.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe page code:

```
    <html>    
    <head>   
    <title>something</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">       
    switch (window.parent.document.title) {         
        case  "main": window.parent.document.getElementById("class1").className = "marked";break;
        case "About": window.parent.document.getElementById("class2").className = "marked";break;
        case "Interesting facts":             
    document.getElementById("class3").className =  "marked";break;
        default: alert("I failed, sorry! :(");   break; 
     }    
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body></body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `break;` after each `case`. See, whenever a `case` is valid, the following commands will be executed until stopped by a `break`:

```
switch(value){
   case c0: f0();
   case c1: f1();
   case c2: f2();
   default: f3();
}
```

Now if `value` equals `c1`, `f1()` will be executed. The next label (`case c2`) instead `f2` is called, so is `f2` and `f3`. You need to stop the execution of the cases:

```
switch(value){
   case c0: f0(); break;
   case c1: f1(); break;
   case c2: f2(); break;
   default: f3(); break; // doesn't really need a break since it is the last
}
```

While this might seem counter-intuitive at first, that's the only way to follow the DRY concept:

```
switch(myletter){
   case 'A':
   case 'B':
   case 'C': alert("Hey, it's either A,B or C"); break;
   default: alert("Sorry, I don't know this letter yet :/");
}
```

For more information see [MDN: switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: it still doesn't perform the class change. does it matter if the title is in hebrew or arabic,(not in eמglish)?